# Unable send JSON response in POST request React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, http-post

I have a submit button when clicked a set of JSON response has to be sent to the server. Below is snippet of my code. Though there are no errors The app doesn't send json response to server.

```
class Slide extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {visible: false};
        this.state = {
            options: [{key: 0, text: 'None', value: 0},
                {key: 1, text: 'Chord Daigram', value: 1},
                {key: 2, text: 'Pie Chart', value: 2},
                {key: 3, text: 'Heat Map', value: 3},
                {key: 4, text: 'Bar Chart', value: 4}]
        };


        this.toggleVisibility = () => this.setState({visible: !this.state.visible}),
            this.clearSelection = () => this.setState({options: this.state.options});

    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.update();
    }

    update() {
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/interact/ID/update',
            data: {
                ID: 'KE-0604',
                visibility: 'False'
            }

        });
    }


    render() {
        const {visible, clearSelection} = this.state
        return (
            <div>
                <Sidebar.Pushable as={Segment}>
                    <div className="ui icon Button">
                        <Button basic floated='right' icon onClick={this.toggleVisibility}><Icon name='align justify'/></Button>
                    </div>
                    <Sidebar
                        as={Menu}
                        animation='overlay'
                        width='very wide'
                        direction='right'
                        visible={visible}
                        icon='labeled'
                        vertical>
                        <Segment>
                            <div>
                                <Container textAlign='right'>
                                    <Icon onClick={this.toggleVisibility} floated='right'>
                                        <Icon name='close'
                                              size='large'/>
                                    </Icon>
                                </Container>
                            </div>
                            <br/>
                            <div floated='right'>
                                <Dropdown placeholder='Select Visualization' selection options={options}/>
                            </div>
                            <br/>
                            <Combobox/>
                            <br/>
                            <Button primary floated='left' size='small' onClick={this.update}>Submit </Button>
                            <Button positive floated='left' size='small' onClick={options}>Reset</Button>
                            <br/>
                            <br/>
                        </Segment>
                    </Sidebar>
                    <Sidebar.Pusher>
                        <Chord/>
                    </Sidebar.Pusher>
                </Sidebar.Pushable>
            </div>
        )
    }
};

export default Slide;
```

After clicking the submit button the server would then send out a fresh set of data by changing visibility. In my code nothing works post clicking the submit button.

Comment: Just start with some basic debugging and put an `alert()` in your `update()`.

Comment: Added `alert()` in `update()`. The alert is popping up by-default. Also the alert is working with onclick on Submit. But the Post API isn't working.

Comment: In that case, provided the browser doesn't show any error messages at all (I suspect a CORS issue), you need to add error handling to your `axios` call.